# Powershell - Export Count of Groups Members to excel

Tags: excel, powershell, azure-active-directory

```
       foreach ($group in $ADMSObjects){
    
            $searchString = $group.GroupDisplayName
            $count = (Get-AzureADGroup -All $true -SearchString "$searchString" | Get-AzureADGroupMember -ALL 1).COUNT
            write-host $group.GroupDisplayName  , $count 
            
       }
```

I just need the function 'extended' to actually export $group.GroupDisplayName and $count to an Excel Sheet.

When I try to do something like:

```
       foreach ($group in $ADMSObjects){
    
            $searchString = $group.GroupDisplayName
            $count = (Get-AzureADGroup -All $true -SearchString "$searchString" | Get-AzureADGroupMember -ALL 1).COUNT
            write-host $group.GroupDisplayName  , $count 
            Export-Csv -Path $path $group, $count -Append
            
       }
```

```
DLAS - AMER - Global Planning and Transformation - 1190-GO-CGPT10026 32
Export-Csv : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.Char' required by parameter 
'Delimiter'. Specified method is not supported.
At C:\users\crxdan\Documents\Set-DLASGroups.ps1:220 char:36
+             Export-Csv -Path $path $group, $count -Append
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

you could use PSCustomObject to get your results in an order. I guess the `$group` you mentioned is group display name. I do not have an environment to test it. so please test it from your end. Thanks!

```
$result = foreach ($group in $ADMSObjects){
    
   $searchString = $group.GroupDisplayName
   $count = (Get-AzureADGroup -All $true -SearchString "$searchString" | Get-AzureADGroupMember -ALL 1).COUNT
   write-host $group.GroupDisplayName  , $count

    [PSCustomObject]@{
            Group = $group.GroupDisplayName 
            Count = $Count
        }
}
$result | Export-Csv -Path $path -Append
```

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce  the scenario in my environment:***

*Note: To print display name:*
Run using ***`$group.DisplayName`***

Used below code:

```
$azgroups=Get-AzureADGroup
foreach ($group in $azgroups){
$searchString = $group.GroupDisplayName
$count = (Get-AzureADGroup -All $true -SearchString "$searchString" | Get-AzureADGroupMember -ALL 1).COUNT

write-host $group.DisplayName  , $count

$group_properties = [pscustomobject] @{
"DisplayName" = $group.DisplayName
"Count" = $count
}
$group_properties | Export-csv -Path  C:\User\xxx\myexcelsheet" -NoTypeInformation -Force -Append
}
```

[image]

The csv or excel file is created successfully:

[image]

And we could see the required fiels in the csv file

[image]